# Как выбрать json-элемент в postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

Имеется таблица **tbl** , в ней поле **msg** с типом **json** в которой куча записей одна из которых содержит:

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "GUID": "1343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205719",
            "Date": "2017-11-29T17:55:46",
        },{
            "GUID": "2343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205718",
            "Date": "2017-11-29T17:55:46",
        }
    ]
}
```

Как составить запрос поиска записи по GUID = 1343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, data from testjs 
where exists(
    select from jsonb_array_elements(testjs.data->'item') el 
    where el->>'GUID' = '1343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205719'
);
```

Решение рабочее, но не эффективное, т.к. не может использовать индексы, а использует полный перебор таблицы.

```
 Seq Scan on testjs  (cost=0.00..1541.97 rows=499 width=203) (actual time=0.031..3.677 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (SubPlan 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 997
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Function Scan on jsonb_array_elements el  (cost=0.01..1.50 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=998)
           Filter: ((value ->> 'GUID'::text) = '1343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205719'::text)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning time: 0.100 ms
 Execution time: 3.703 ms
(9 строк)
```

Чтобы искать данные эффективно можно создать функцию, которая будет возвращать массив guid элементов:

```
create or replace function jsonb_guid_index(js jsonb) 
returns text[] as $$ 
    select array_agg(el->>'GUID') from jsonb_array_elements(js) as el; 
$$ immutable language sql;
```

И создать по этой функции gin-индекс:

```
create index concurrently testjs_gin on testjs using gin(jsonb_guid_index(data->'item'));
```

Для использования этого индекса запрос будет выглядеть вот так:

```
select id from testjs 
where jsonb_guid_index(data->'item') @> array['1343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205719'];
```

В `explain analyze` теперь видно, что используется индекс и всё хорошо.

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on testjs  (cost=8.01..12.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (jsonb_guid_index((data -> 'item'::text)) @> '{1343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205719}'::text[])
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on testjs_gin  (cost=0.00..8.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (jsonb_guid_index((data -> 'item'::text)) @> '{1343f637-d7d3-11e6-8a2b-000c29205719}'::text[])
 Planning time: 0.159 ms
 Execution time: 0.047 ms
```

Эффект от индекса даже заметен всего на моей тестовой тысяче документов.

---

Возможно, вас скорее заинтересует расширение [`jsquery`](https://github.com/postgrespro/jsquery), которое как раз для подобного класса задач должно подходить. Но оно пока не поставляется вместе с postgresql и уже для jsonb.

В обоих случаях требуется postgresql 9.4 или новее. Для более старых версий выкрутиться возможно аналогично через gin индекс по функции, но функцию придётся писать на чём-нибудь другом. `pl/perl` или `pl/python` например, которые получают на вход json документ, а возвращают массив text с guid'ами.